# Understanding basic windows programming for vs2010

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm coming from a unix background but I'm being asked to do some windows programming and I'm having trouble understanding the framework.  What's the general hierarchy between win32, mfc, .NET, etc.

Is there a decent tutorial online that goes over the general structure of Windows programming.  I'm not exactly sure what I should be searching for.

Comment: This is perfecly valid for someone who has no idea where to start.  Sheesh. I'd ask similary basic questions if I were to go start coding for a different Operating System.  Heck, a few years back, I'd have asked such questions about Linux.

Comment: It's covered in the FAQ (link up on top of the page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

win32 is the actual Windows API which provides the objects and functions necessary to create a windows application.

MFC is a C++-based framework for creating Windows applications. It's built on top of the win32 API. If you'd like to write your application in C++, then this is probably your best bet.

.NET is a managed framework for writing applications, and contains both WinForms and WPF for writing applications based on the win32 API. If you'd like to use VB or C#, then that is the way to go.

Comment: Almost exactly what my answer was going to be.  I'd add that .NET more closely related to Java programming, in that it's got a class library, it's a bytecode language that runs on top of Windows.  VB.NET and C# and other supported .NET languages all get compiled down to the same bytecode, which allows them to run on in the same CLR (similar conceptually to the Java VM)


It's far easier to use and learn, and if you've got Java background, learning C# should be relatively easy.  Also, given the direction Windows is going leanring .NET puts you in a better position to support future development.

Comment: so I can think of MFC as a library to further abstract the windows api?  thanks!

Comment: @Brian Right. The original API requires a fair amount of "book-keeping", a lot of which will be taken care of for you by MFC. Good luck!